# Access conda python kernel from non-conda jupyter installation

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, conda, pyzmq

I have Python 3.7 installed from python.org with jupyter installed via pip.

I then separately have a miniconda installation in which I have installed ipykernel and run some different invocations of `ipython kernel install` (according to [this](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html)) to make the conda-based kernel visible to JupyterLab.

If I run jupyter kernelspec list I see the following:

```
  conda37_freecad      c:\python37\share\jupyter\kernels\conda37_freecad
  python3              c:\python37\share\jupyter\kernels\python3
  python_37_freecad    C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels\python_37_freecad
```

If I try to select the `conda37_freecad` or `python_37_freecad` I get

```
C:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cffi\__pycache__\_cffi_ext.c(213): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/un.h': No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\miniconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "C:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\connect.py", line 18, in <module>
    import jupyter_client
  File "C:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "C:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 23, in <module>
    import zmq
  File "C:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "C:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

It seems like the when the kernel starts up its not properly activating the base environment. I think a conda-based jupyter installation would be able to take advantage of `nb_conda_kernels` which perhaps handles the activation bit.

While this is a bit unusual, it should be reproducible. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, everything looks fine from the `kernelspec` perspective. The error seems to be with that `zmq` module.  I.e., it doesn't look like a Jupyter issue to me.

Comment: My theory was that zmq just happened to be the first failure because its one of the first libraries called by ipykernel and without an activated environment, it was unable to find it's dll. When a conda environment is active there are I think 5 folders added to the path that help with imports and dll loading.

Comment: To me, it looks like Conda env paths are correctly being referenced. For comparison, when I check one of my envs that I have configured to use externally (from Hydrogen in Atom), it has Cython compiled versions of all the source files I see referenced in your `zmq`-related error (e.g., (constants|context|error|message|socket).*.so) in the folder `envs/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zmq/backend/cython/`.  Can you verify that you have the Windows equivalent (i.e., `.dll` files) in the directory your Python is searching?

Comment: It's a bunch of *.pyd files (so... basically `*.dll's`). The failing line of `__init__.py` is just an import of all the modules in the current folder, which are all there as `*.pyd` files with no corresponding dll anywhere. Reading some related `zmq` bugs it looks like the cython pyd's are probably not linking against the `msvcp140.dll` which conda puts in `Library\bin` which gets added to the path in conda activation. Indeed, if I run the anaconda prompt, then explicitly start my python.org/pip-based jupyter lab, it is able to use both python.org and conda-based kernels.

Comment: Made a related comment over at ipykernel tracker. They are talking about environment activation on kernel selection... lucky timing? https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/416#issuecomment-515427179